# \scalebox doesn't compile

Tags: errors, boxes, scaling

I want to scale down an equation and after trying lots of examples found on the internet I still cannot compile or see what is wrong. My code looks like:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
....
\scalebox{0.7}{
\begin{equation} \label{eq_iinf}
 entropy(C_j)=-{\sum_{c_j \in C_j}{P(c_j)\log_2 P(c_j)}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{eq_P}
 P(c_j)=\frac{fs(c_j)}{\sum_{c'_j \in C_j}{fs(c'_j)}}
\end{equation}
}
```

And the errors are very long, but it complains something like "missing $ inserted" and "you can't use `eqno` in math mode"
which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: @Ziqi Could you maybe accept the answer if it was helpful? This will mark the question as complete which helps other users as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use

```
\scalebox{0.7}{\parbox{\linewidth}{%
  ...
}}
```

Otherwise you'll get two paragraphs inside `scalebox`. However, two equation environments can be replaced by one of the `align` environments from `amsmath`.

Comment: +1 but this [link (click)](http://tug.org/PSTricks/Examples/Gallery/exa098.tex) is broken.

Comment: @Hebebert, the `\scalebox` turns the equation inside it into inline equation, which is not desired. How to fix this?

Comment: I cannot see that it will be an inline equation. Give an example